# code name for visual studio solution and projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Imagine we have an idea for a product and we do not know under what name we will eventually market that idea, thus we start with a "code name". For example, imagine we have an idea for a product that can add two numbers. We give it the code name "Algorithma" and create a solution, many projects such as "Algorithma.Proj1", "Algorithma.Proj2", db projects and so on.

Later on we market the product as "FancyAlgo". Now the code name is different than the actual name of the product. Is there some way that Visual Studio can handle this so we can rename everything in one shot?

The reason I ask is because in the past renaming projects have given me a hard time. Sure, I can do this manually as specified in the duplicate question but this is such a common thing that we all face so I am wondering if I am missing out on a feature here.

Comment: AFAIK, unfortunately, no. This kind of rename is real PITA. Would love to see some ideas about it though

Comment: I've found [this](https://codeaddiction.net/articles/29/rename-a-project-in-visual-studio-resharpertfs) to be a pretty helpful reference for renaming a solution and projects. It's still a pretty manual process. Also, it helps a lot to have Resharper.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed That question is telling me how to do what I want, I already know how to do it (manually). But is that the only way?

Comment: I'm not aware of any other way, let alone if you're using source control.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed ok you are not aware, but you just closed my question so how can others give answer???

Comment: I did not close your question, I don't even have the required privileges to do so. I simply flagged it _to be reviewed by those who have the required privileges to determine if it's a duplicate or not_. If you believe it's not a duplicate, you can edit it and/or vote for re-open. You probably know all this already!